# Git branch -b "branch name" creation from master?

Tags: git

I am using the command shell to create git branches using command git branch -b "branchname". Will the branch be empty with no files, or will it create the branch from master ? when I do dir on the folder, I am seeing a list of files.

Thanks !

Comment: Seems like you just answered your own question.

Comment: Branches are labels for a commit. Commits contain a snapshot of the code at a certain time.

Comment: You might like this site: [Visualizing Git](https://git-school.github.io/visualizing-git/). It is a nice little tool that illustrates how Git works when running various commands.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `git branch X` the branch `X` is created at the currently checked out commit (i.e. `HEAD`). This could be `master` if you are currently on master; you can verify with `git rev-parse HEAD`.

Note that `git branch X` does not checkout the branch. You have to use `git checkout X` after the branch was created. To combine both into a single command, you can use `git checkout -b X`.

To create a branch at a specific commit, provide a revspec as second parameter to either `git branch` or `git checkout -b`:

- `git branch X master`: creates branch X at the latest commit of `master` branch.
- `git checkout -b X master`: creates and checks out branch X at the latest commit of `master` branch.

At that point `X` and `master` are identical: they both point to the same commit, thus contain the same history and show the same files when checked out.

If you want to create a new branch without any relation to existing branches, you can use [`git checkout --orphan X master`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---orphanltnewbranchgt):

> `--orphan <new_branch>`
>
> Create a new orphan branch, named `<new_branch>`, started from `<start_point>` and switch to it. The first commit made on this new branch will have no parents and it will be the root of a new history totally disconnected from all the other branches and commits.
>
> The index and the working tree are adjusted as if you had previously run `git checkout <start_point>`. This allows you to start a new history that records a set of paths similar to `<start_point>` by easily running `git commit -a` to make the root commit.
>
> This can be useful when you want to publish the tree from a commit without exposing its full history. You might want to do this to publish an open source branch of a project whose current tree is "clean", but whose full history contains proprietary or otherwise encumbered bits of code.
>
> If you want to start a disconnected history that records a set of paths that is totally different from the one of `<start_point>`, then you should clear the index and the working tree right after creating the orphan branch by running `git rm -rf .` from the top level of the working tree. Afterwards you will be ready to prepare your new files, repopulating the working tree, by copying them from elsewhere, extracting a tarball, etc.